# Capybara test case for Login page authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I have capybara test case below.

```
it "Testing login page with valid data" do
  fill_in 'email', with: 'kiran@gmail.com'
  expect(page).to have_selector("input[value='kiran@gmail.com']")#Checking values are inserted in email field

  fill_in 'password', with: 'Kiran.6565'
  expect(page).to have_selector("input[value='Kiran.6565']")#Checking values are inserted in password field

  click_button('submit')

  expect(current_path).to eql(patient_detail_path(4))

end
```

I am checking Login page once the email and password fields are matches it should redirect to patient_details_path with id field value. In above code i specified email and password is working fine for manual login, but problem is in test case. Expected result: it should redirect to another page(patient_details_path) but it redirecting to home page(/) again.

```
Failures:

1) Login Page Interface Test login page with valid data
   Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eql(patient_detail_path(4))

   expected: "/patient_details/4"
        got: "/"

   (compared using eql?)
 # ./spec/views/login_spec.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.08 seconds (files took 2.13 seconds to load)
14 examples, 1 failure
```

I tried different solution's from stackoverflow but nothing work for me. Below are the different solution's tried.

```
#expect(current_path).to eql(patient_detail_path(4))
#expect(page).to have_current_path(patient_detail_path(4))
```

If email and password mismatch it will throw an error and redirect to login page again. In my scenario it was throwing an error even if email and password are valid . If i add below code in my test case it will work pass the test case.

```
#expect(page).to have_content "Invalid username/password combination"
```

Any one please help me i am new to ruby on rails and capybara.

Comment: What happens if you do it manyally, not via Capybara tests? Do you have expected results?

Comment: Where is the code that is creating the user with the given email and password and also the patients so that you have a valid patient with id of 4?  Also, you should always be using the `have_current_path` matcher when testing the path -- the way your current test has it will be flaky.  Also this isn't a view spec so it shouldn't be in /spec/views/.

Comment: @meta Yes manually if i login it will work.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thanks for you advice. I appreciate you time for sharing with me.

Comment: All your solution's will work but problem in my case is test database. When i fill values and submit in test database it's clearing the data so i tried inserting values in test machine and i tested it is working. Other alternative way in rspec_helper file comment database clear statement it will work. Thanks for all your responds and appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the test you're trying to write should be written something like

```
before :each do
  @user = # Create the required user with whatever method you're using
  @patient = # Create the required patient with whatever method you're using
end

it "Logs in with valid data" do
  visit(patient_detail_path(@patient)) # gets redirected to the login path
  fill_in 'email', with: 'kiran@gmail.com'
  fill_in 'password', with: 'Kiran.6565'
  click_button('submit')

  expect(page).to have_current_path(patient_detail_path(@patient))
end
```

That's a general guess and might not be 100% correct (tough to guess exactly what you're trying to do with half the test missing - the before block - from your question) but the general parts should be there.  Since yours isn't logging in I'm guessing you're not actually creating a valid user with the given email and password, or you don't have a patient created with an id of 4 (you really shouldn't be relying on testing specific id numbers in feature tests though).

Additionally, you should always use the `have_current_path` matcher when checking for a given path/url since it will prevent test flakiness and since it's not a view test it shouldn't be in `spec/views/login_spec.rb`, more appropriate would be `spec/features/login_spec.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the driver is capturing the URL before Rails has a chance to update the URL to reflect the new page.

Asserting on URL is hard after performing a navigation change as a race condition might appear. I would suggest:

Assert on some other piece of info that could verify the user successfully logged in.
Assert using the wait option.

`expect(page).to have_current_path(patient_detail_path(@patient), wait: 3)`